# SQL Server 2008R2: 'DELETE FROM' hangs forever, but 'SELECT' works fine

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, delete-row, table-locking

I'm not a DBA by any means, so I'm lost on this one. I have a table with 152,000 rows in it. I'm trying to execute this statement:

`DELETE FROM FILES WHERE Asset_Id = 340`

And it hangs forever in the query window -- just says "Executing query...". This statement works fine:

`SELECT * FROM FILES`

I also have a copy of the DB  that I tried the delete statement on, and it ran in less than a couple seconds with no issue. So there must be something going on with that table. What could possibly be going on here? It's affecting functionality in my web app.

Thanks.

Comment: Any triggers on the table or referential integrity? Also when it is hung have a look at `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks`

Comment: Google's telling me referential integrity means there's a column in this table that's referenced by every other table in the DB, and that's not the case...

Comment: Any foreign keys that reference `FILES` that would need to be validated or might have cascade actions.

Comment: No foreign keys with cascade actions, but there are foreign keys to the File_Id column on this table, yes.

Comment: Are they big tables? Are those columns indexed? But first look at `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` and see if it is blocked on something.

Comment: select * from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks did return 30 rows. What am I looking for specifically?

Comment: Not big tables, per se. The columns have not been explicitly indexed that I'm aware of. It's worth noting again, though, that the DELETE statement worked fine a copy of this DB.

Comment: Try `SELECT wait_type,resource_address FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks WHERE session_id > 50` unless you happen to know the exact session_id  of the blocked connection (if you are running the statement in management studio the session_id is the number in brackets shown in the tab)

Comment: No rows from that query. The highest session_id I have in that table is 17.

Comment: You ran it whilst the DELETE was running and apparently hung?

Comment: Apologies, no I didn't. And when I just tried to run and have it hang, the DELETE statement ran with no issue. If a job or something was running that was touching that table, could that have caused this?

Comment: Well it would have needed to read the other tables with foreign keys on the `File_Id` column to validate that it wouldn't leave any orphaned records so it might have been blocked waiting on a shared lock on one of those rows. This could happen if that table had an outstanding data modification transaction that hadn't been committed but now has been.

Comment: Interesting.. so this doesn't sound like it's index-related, in that if I had an index on Asset_Id (as Metaphor suggested) it could have preempted this issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27653/discussion-between-matt-powell-and-martin-smith)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an index on Asset_Id.

Comment: Not really. That wouldn't apparently hang "forever" on such a small table.

Comment: That was my question just now in the comments. Thanks.